# MudNavGroup expands toggles when I click on MudNavLink. How do I keep the group open

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

What needs to happen, is when I click on a MudNavLink the MudNavGroup should stay open.  Just like it does on the MudBlazor Docs site.  However, if I click on the link it toggles the group closed.

Is there a better way to get this behavior?

```
        <MudNavGroup Title="Exams" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Settings" Expanded="@Exams"
                 @onclick="@(e => Exams = !Exams)">
        <MudNavLink Title="Find Exam" href="findExam" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AdminPanelSettings" >Find an Exam</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Title="Find Exam" href="ModifyRegistration" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AdminPanelSettings" >Modify Registration</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Title="Find Exam" href="RegistrationForExam" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AdminPanelSettings" >Registration For Exam</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavGroup>
    
    <MudNavGroup Title="Laurel Information" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Settings" Expanded="@Info"
                 @onclick="@(e => Info = !Info)">
        <MudNavLink Href="/Officers" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt" >Credits</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/Coordinators" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt" >Coordinators</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/Webmaster" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt" >Webmasters</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/Credits" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt" >Webmasters</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanded is a two way boolean property [Docs](https://mudblazor.com/api/navgroup#properties). So you need to prefix it with a `@bind-` so that the states of the boolean values are preserved.

And the `@onclick` is already embedded into the component so you can remove that.

If you want to run your own custom logic when it's clicked then you can use `Expanded` and `ExpandedChanged` instead of `@bind-Expanded`

```html
<MudNavGroup @bind-Expanded="@Exams" Title="Exams" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Settings">
    <MudNavLink Title="Find Exam" href="findExam" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AdminPanelSettings" >Find an Exam</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Title="Find Exam" href="ModifyRegistration" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AdminPanelSettings" >Modify Registration</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Title="Find Exam" href="RegistrationForExam" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AdminPanelSettings" >Registration For Exam</MudNavLink>
</MudNavGroup>
    
<MudNavGroup @bind-Expanded="@Info" Title="Laurel Information" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Settings">
    <MudNavLink Href="/Officers" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt" >Credits</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/Coordinators" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt" >Coordinators</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/Webmaster" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt" >Webmasters</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/Credits" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt" >Webmasters</MudNavLink>
</MudNavGroup>
```

Comment: Well, this is interesting.  What you said worked, except if the link wasn't defined.  Then it would close the group.  Of course, the correct solution is to have all the links defined. This is great and will save me a lot of time.